# SizeToFit and Autolayout on UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have a dynamic cell with autolayout that has an image and a dynamic label. Currently I try to draw the bubble image but I need to know what is the size of the label given its text. I have to say that I always receive a bad size and when I scroll the tableview, the bubble image is placed corectlly but it ads another bubble.

Here is my code:

```
func imageCellAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> SenderTableViewCell{
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SenderIdentifier") as! SenderTableViewCell
    cell.senderMessageLAbel.text = "fadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdadfasdfsb"
    cell.senderMessageLAbel.sizeToFit()
    cell.senderNameLabel.text = "Stefan"

    let padding: CGFloat = 10.0

    // 4. Calculation of new width and height of the chat bubble view
    var viewHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    var viewWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

        viewHeight = cell.senderMessageLAbel.frame.size.height + padding
        viewWidth = cell.senderMessageLAbel.frame.size.width  + padding/2

    if viewHeight > viewWidth {
        viewHeight = cell.senderMessageLAbel.frame.size.width  + padding/2
        viewWidth = cell.senderMessageLAbel.frame.size.height + padding
    }

    let bubbleImageFileName = "bubbleMine"
    let imageViewBG : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(cell.senderMessageLAbel.frame.origin.x - 5, cell.senderMessageLAbel.frame.origin.y - 10,viewWidth,viewHeight ))
    imageViewBG.image = UIImage(named: bubbleImageFileName)?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(14, 22,17 , 20))
    cell.insertSubview(imageViewBG, atIndex: 0)
    imageViewBG.center = cell.senderMessageLAbel.center

    return cell
}
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your function is being called at `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function of UICollectionView DataSource. That function is called multiple times, whenever there is a need of drawing collection view cells that come into view. So each time that happens, you're inserting `imageViewBG` to the cell, and hence the duplicates.

A quick solution would be to add a specific tag to the `imageViewBG` as below and remove it each time before re-adding it.

```
cell.viewWithTag(99)?.removeFromSuperview()
let imageViewBG = //Configure
imageViewBG.tag = 99
cell.insertSubview(imageViewBG, atIndex: 0)
```

Although this would help solve the duplicates problem, I would **strongly suggest** you to add the imageView to your custom cell on the storyboard and configure the image that it should display in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` .